# Problem with gnuplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

[fr] La 1ere figure ci-dessous permet de représenter la conversion analogique numérique avec `\NN`  le nombre de niveaux, réalisée avec le code suivant (il faut autoriser gnuplot). Comme vous pouvez le constater, la deuxième figure n'est pas complète, la seule différence est dans l'appel de la fonction, dans la seconde, j'ai généralisée en précisant `\NN`

[en] The first figure below is used to represent the analog to digital conversion with `\NN` the number of levels, performed with the following code (you have to allow gnuplot). As you can see, the second figure is not complete, the only difference is in the function call in the second, I generalized by specifying `\NN`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\NN{16}
\begin{scope}[xscale=6,yscale=2]
\draw[draw=red,,fill=pink] plot[id=sin9c,prefix=gnuplot/,domain=0:2,samples=60,
ybar interval] 
function{0.25*floor(\NN/4*(sin(4*x)+0.5*sin(20*x)+0.05*sin(200*x)+0.03*sin(400*x)+2))};
\draw[color=blue,thick] plot[id=sin7c,prefix=gnuplot/,domain=0:2,samples=1000,thick] 
function{sin(4*x)+0.5*sin(20*x)+0.05*sin(200*x)+0.03*sin(400*x)+2};
\foreach \nn in{0,1,2,...,\NN}{
\draw (0,{2*\nn/(\NN/2)}) node[left]{\small \nn}-- (2,{2*\nn/(\NN/2)});
}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\NN{16}
\begin{scope}[xscale=6,yscale=2]
\draw[draw=red,,fill=pink] plot[id=sin9c,prefix=gnuplot/,domain=0:2,samples=60,
ybar interval] 
function{4/\NN*floor(\NN/4*(sin(4*x)+0.5*sin(20*x)+0.05*sin(200*x)
+0.03*sin(400*x)+2))};
\draw[color=blue,thick] plot[id=sin7c,prefix=gnuplot/,domain=0:2,samples=1000,thick]
 function{sin(4*x)+0.5*sin(20*x)+0.05*sin(200*x)+0.03*sin(400*x)+2};
\foreach \nn in{0,1,2,...,\NN}{
\draw (0,{2*\nn/(\NN/2)}) node[left]{\small \nn}-- (2,{2*\nn/(\NN/2)});
}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment faire pour obtenir la courbe? / How to obtain the curve?

Comment: I cannot test it now, but in gnuplot 4/16 is an integer division, son 4/16=0. If you want to obtain 0.25 you must write something like 4.0/16. Look at [expressions section of gnuplot manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-5200013)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you divide two integers (as in your second case, `4/\NN=4/16`), gnuplot will use integer arithmetic, so the result of the expression is `4/16=0`. Use `4.0/\NN` instead, and the two plots are identical.

Comment: If you want divide two integer macros (like `\nn/\mm`), you can use `(\nn*1.0)/\mm`.